# How to load Captcha faster in MVC4 Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added Captcha in ASP.NET MVC 4 application. Usually, it takes time to load captcha for the first time. Then it is working fine with perfect speed. But for the first time, it takes time.

Here is my cade: Can anybody suggest me to load it faster?(by loading dll or anything else)

```
DLL: SRVTextToImage
```

CSTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    img = document.getElementById("img_captcha");
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    debugger;
    @*img.src='@Url.Action("GetCaptchImage", "Contact")?'+n;*@
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCaptchImage", "Contact")?'+n,
    }).done(function(response) {
        var filePath = "contact/GetCaptchImage?"+n;
        img.src=filePath;
        document.getElementById('span_loading').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('img_captcha').style.display = 'inline-block';
    });
</script>

<img src="" id="img_captcha" style="width: 200px;display: none;vertical-align: middle;" />
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public FileResult GetCaptchImage()
{
    CaptchaRandomImage CI = new CaptchaRandomImage();
    this.Session["CaptchaImageText"] = CI.GetRandomString(5);
    CI.GenerateImage(this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 300, 75, Color.DarkGray, Color.White);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    CI.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another and easy solution to integrate Recaptcha. Try using Google Recapture which is easy to use and integrate.

Go to : [Google Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Register a new site which will provide you a site key which will used in the following way:

Paste this snippet before the closing  tag on your HTML template:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Paste this snippet at the end of the  where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Your recaptcha Sitekey"></div>
```

And don't forget to add your domain to Key Settings when you create Recaptcha key.